# What is the name of the Highcharts type interface that provides series types?

Tags: typescript, highcharts

I need the type definition of Highcharts series types. With this code:

`type: 'seriesType'`

I get the error:

> Type '"seriesType"' is not assignable to type '"line" | "spline" | "bar" | "column" | "area" | "areaspline" | "map" | "polygon" | "abands" | "ad" | "ao" | "apo" | "arearange" | "areasplinerange" | "aroon" | "aroonoscillator" | ... 84 more ... | "zigzag"'.

But I cannot find the TypeScript type / interface that includes all of the types it is asking for.

I have found type `Series` which is defined as:

> (alias) class Series
>   (alias) interface Series
>   import Series
>   This is the base series prototype that all other series types inherit from. A new series is initialized either through the series option structure, or after the chart is initialized, through Highcharts.Chart#addSeries.

But this sounds like overkill. I just need the type that is made up of those 100 or so strings.

What it the name of the type that includes all of these types?

Comment: Hi @Mr. Robot, That is probably interface `SeriesTypesDictionary`. Please check it and let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek when trying to use this type I get the error `node_modules/highcharts/highcharts"' has no exported member 'SeriesTypesDictionary'`. I am using highcharts v8.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The TS definition you are looking for is not in the public API. You could open TS directory in the Highcharts GitHub repo and look for the internal type `SeriesTypesDictionary` (as Paweł suggested in the comments), but this will not be accessible in the released Highcharts code.

Instead of that, you could use `SeriesOptionsRegistry` - this is the closest type to what you asked for in the public API. It is a registry of all series options object types and goes like this:

```
/**
 * The registry for all types of series options.
 */
export interface SeriesOptionsRegistry {
    SeriesAbandsOptions: SeriesAbandsOptions;
    SeriesAdOptions: SeriesAdOptions;
    SeriesAoOptions: SeriesAoOptions;
    SeriesApoOptions: SeriesApoOptions;
...and all other series options types...
```

Comment: In case you need more then there is you can always open a feature request through a GitHub issue in the Highcharts main repository - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Type%3A+Feature+Request&template=feature_request.md&title=